# Почему в turf функция union выдает ошибку found non-noded intersection

Tags: javascript

В `turf` ломается функция `union` при объединении полигонов. Почему так происходит?

```
var polygons_data = [
[[[-150.46681563135994,-1.439821242368066],[-153.61494141185997,2.3379296942319727],[-151.8279192046993,0.19350304563917356],[-150.46681563135994,-1.439821242368066]]],
[[[-168.293895,0.815157],[-151.8456612595276,0.2147935114331218],[-159.178835,-0.599073],[-168.293895,0.815157]]]
];
var polygons = [];
for (var i=0; i<polygons_data.length; i++) {    
  polygons.push(turf.polygon(polygons_data[i]));  
}
console.log(turf.union(polygons[0], polygons[1]));
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
uncaught exception: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection
between LINESTRING ( -150.46681563135994 -1.439821242368066,-151.8456612595276 0.21479351143312128 ) and LINESTRING ( -151.8456612595276 0.21479351143312186, -151.8279192046993 0.19350304563917356 )
```

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/nikolya/p9b3vtm5/11/).

Answer (score 0):

Мержить можно только объекты типа Polygon.
А тут лайнстринг.